# Using polar coordinates, calculate the double integral

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} \qquad D:\{x^2 +y^2 \leq 1;~ x\leq 0;~ y \geq \sqrt{3}x \}
$$
Can you help me please?

Comment: Could you please write out your integral?

Comment: I 'm not very good at it, a whole new theme for me:(

Comment: @AnginaSeng I attached a photo

Comment: @AnginaSeng there is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x, y)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}$ transform your function
to polar form ($f(r, \theta)$) by using $r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ then the domain in polar form:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\text { (using the given transformations for r) } \\
D=\left\{(r, \theta): 0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1, \frac{\pi}{2} \leqslant \theta \leq \frac{4 \pi}{3}\right\}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
, integral will be $\int_{\pi / 2}^{4 \pi / 3} \int_{0}^{1} f(r, \theta) r\, d r\, d \theta$
\begin{equation}
=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{4 \pi}{3}} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{r}{1+r^{2}}\, d r\, d \theta
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
=&\int_{\pi/2}^{4 \pi / 3}\left[\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r}{1+r^{2}} d r\right] d \theta\\
&=\int_{\pi/2}^{4\pi/3}\left[\frac{\ln \left(1+r^{2}\right)}{2}\right]_{0}^{1} d \theta
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
=& \int_{\pi / 2}^{4 \pi / 3} \frac{\ln (2)}{2} d \theta \\
=& \frac{\ln (2)}{2}[\theta]_{\pi / 2}^{4 \pi / 3} \\
=& \frac{\ln (2)}{2}\left(\frac{4 \pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\
=& \frac{\ln (2)}{2}\left(\frac{5 \pi}{6}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: What I need to do next, I don 't know how to solve anything like that yet

Comment: @Alex which is an iterated integral you just calculate in a similar way to the single integral (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_integral), last edit will help.

Comment: thanks, you very much helped me

Comment: I can 't come to this answer(( (5/12pi*log(2)

Comment: @Alex Which step you are thinking that the answers are deviated

Comment: I can 't say exactly, I have a lot of decisions and all the answers vary, I'm so sorry

Comment: I'll edit and add all steps

Comment: I am very grateful to you, you save me